# Controller not loading .AspNetCore.Identity.Application user cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a simple controller which is called after the user logs in.  I can see on my identity server that the user is logged in.  I can also see that .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie is set in the browser.

After login the user is forwarded to this controller using

```
RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "Manage")
```

The problem is that the controller doesn't appear to be authenticated.  I have tried HttpContext.User and everything else i can think the controller isn't reading the cookie

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ManageController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message = null)
    {

      //  try to find user here.
    }
}
```

I have found a work around which forces it to load the cookie

```
var loadTheStupidCookie = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(loadTheStupidCookie.Principal);
```

This works but I think its over kill to have to load it in every method in the controller.  Shouldn't the controller be able to load the cookie for me?

From startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
                })
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.AccessType = "offline";
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ClientId = "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "XXXX";
                });
```

Note: Removing  [AllowAnonymous] causes it to not work at all probably due to the fact that it cant see the authentication.

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication()` in the middleware configuration in Startup?

Comment: @juunas yes its in configure.

Comment: Before UseMvc() I assume? :)

Comment: Try `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)]` instead of just `[Authorize]`.

Comment: @juunas yup i checked that first :)

Comment: @serpent5 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)]  says an attribute argument must be a constant expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the `Authorize` attribute, it will use the default `AuthenticationScheme` configured using `AddAuthentication`. In your example, that looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Because this is [`CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationDefaults.cs#L16)("Cookies"), the `Authorize` attribute is using that when attempting to sign the user in. Your workaround shows that you actually wanted to use [`IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityConstants.cs#L15)("Identity.Application")` instead.

The `Authorize` attribute allows you to specify the `AuthenticationScheme`(s) you want to use, using the `AuthenticationSchemes` property, which looks like this:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
```

It turns out you can't use `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` directly, as this is not a compile-time constant. Although you could use the string value explicitly, you can get the compile time safety by setting up a policy, for example. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x#selecting-the-scheme-with-policies) for an example on how to do that.

Comment: Ok so am I doing something wrong with with i have the cookies set up? Or is it ok to do it like this?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing - It's perfectly fine to use multiple `AuthenticationScheme`s and differentiate between them like this. The real question is whether you need both schemes, but that's not something I'm able to answer for your specific project.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't completely solve the problem so I have opened another question related to it.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/47920836/1841839

Comment: Why "Identity.Application" not constant value, but readonly in IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme

Comment: @Novikov I don't know for sure, but I wonder if it's because `readonly` allows for the value to be changed in a new version and for usage to automatically use that new value. If it were `const`, changing it would be a breaking change. It doesn't seem like a strong argument, but that is an important difference between `const` and `readonly`.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the problem this morning.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                })
```

Both DefaultAuthenticateScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme need to be set.   Then  [Authorize] alone works

Leaving this as an alternate solution.