# Identity Server 4 (2.0) not reading Asp.Net Core Identity cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to use [Asp .Net Identity Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) with [Identity Server 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/).   I can see in the logs (Ids) that the user is logged in properly.

> info: Xena.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController[0]
>         User logged in.

My login controller then sends the user over to my Manage controller.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize]
//[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
public class ManageController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message = null)
    {
     ..... 
    }
 }
```

The User never arrives as the login is then lost for some reason.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult[2]
      Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /Manage/Index.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Xena.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController.Login (Xena.IdentityServer) in 3493.6102ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3515.9158ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/Manage/Index
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[2]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Xena.IdentityServer.Controllers.ManageController.Index (Xena.IdentityServer) in 46.2285ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 58.6793ms 401
```

I think part of the clue is this line  `Authorization failed for user: (null).`  I can see that the cookie is in the browser. Its just not being read.

From what I understand Identity server 4 has its own cookies and Asp .Net core Identity has its and they need to be reading the same cookie.  I have tried following [Using ASP.NET Core Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) but it hasn't helped.

**Startup in the Identity server project**

```
 //Adds Asp.net identity 
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaIdentityConnection")));

        // Configuer Asp.net Identity
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>>(config =>
            {
                config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()    // Adds custom SignIn manager.
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


   //https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/signin.html
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            })
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.AccessType = "offline";
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.ClientId = "xxxxx-jvu30c2n19thoqimd97b4jk1r2poh17p.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "g29nXgVoFZBIBNS-hJJxPWXW";
            }).AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "OpenID Connect", options =>
            {
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = settingsSetup.RequireHttpsMetadata;
                options.Authority = settingsSetup.Authority;
                options.ClientId = "testclient";
                options.Scope.Add("testapi");
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });

   services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificate())
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaIdentityConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaIdentityConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));

            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Adding the following does fix my issue with manage/index.  However it doesn't work because then the open Id connect login wont work because that uses internal controllers within Identity Server for authentication that I cant / don't want to overload.  I need to figure out how to get Identity Server 4 to use the cookie set by Aspnet identity or visa versa.

> //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]

*This solution came from a previous question i asked on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792796/controller-not-loading-aspnetcore-identity-application-user-cookie) I have opened a new one because i am leaning towards this being a setup issue with Identity server rather than an issue with Identity cookies*

Comment: This seems a strange setup. I think your problem is that when the redirect from Identity Server to your Controller takes place after authentication, ASP Identity is taking over and rejecting the bearer token. If your using Identity Server as an Identity Provider, why would you want to be using ASP Identity in this way? A better solution would be to look at the Identity Server 4 documentation, and look at how you can incorporate Identity Server's user Store with ASP Identity, and use it for user mgmt only. You can then use openid connect in your client application and setup Idsvr4 as Provider.

Comment: Not sure I understand much of that statement want to try again?  I have been following the identity server tutorials thats how i have gotten this far.   We have a web app which points to the IDs.  Only the Ids has the ability to edit the users as they are within its database.  I need to be able to allow the web api , and 3rd party addons to authenticate to the ids as well as allow users to update their user data.    If i am doing something wrong please elaborate.

Comment: Here is a link to one of the samples i have been following https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/IdentityServerWithAspNetIdentity/Startup.cs

Comment: Apologies, it's difficult to talk through this, I'm assuming that the startup above is the configuration of a client application. And you have ASP Identity setup in the middleware, but why? when authentication is provided by Identity Server. WHat do you need it in your client application for?

Comment: The startup above is conf of the ids not a client.  Login with login and password as well as google is not properly allowing the user to edit their data on the ids.

Comment: can you show the setup of the client?

Comment: Dont actually have a client yet.  I am trying to get the IDs working first.

Comment: What i don't get is i have login, 2fa, register user all that in the account controller and it works but as soon as i try and forward them to another controller (manage) i loose authentication.

Comment: Where is your configuration for the Configuration and Operational Store? and User Store?

Comment: Not 100% sure i know what your talking about. 
  So i am going to guess you mean this .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>() <-- that its at the bottom my configureservices is huge i dont want to post it all.

Comment: Your setup is pretty much identical to mine, apart from the fact I haven't implemented the ProfileService. You could try re-installing all of your nuget packages, I cant see anything wrong with what you have configured.

Comment: I am tempted to create a dummy project and see if that works.   This is an upgrade form IDS 1.x to 2.0 its been frustrating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161736/discussion-between-derek-and-daimto).

Comment: I left work 30 minutes ago :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem this morning.   Part of the problem was due to the fact that I have a custom signin manager which uses the IdentityConstant cookies.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                })
```

Both DefaultAuthenticateScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme need to be set.   Then everything works as it should.

Comment: This worked for the issue we had :0